# AngularJS Use $scope.(parameter)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 2 `buttons` and 2 `contenteditable div`. When I click a `button`, I pass a parameter. Now in the controller, I have a $rootScope.$on() function which appends in the `contenteditable div` so I want to write `$scope.paramter` in the `$rootScope.$on()` method, and in place of parameter I want to put the value I passed as the parameter.

Example:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="open('textModel')">Emojis</button>
<div contenteditable="true" ng-model="textModel"></div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('textModel2')">Emojis</button>
<div contenteditable="true" ng-model="textModel2"></div>
```

//Inside controller

```
$rootScope.$on('selectedCode', function(event, args){
   console.log(btnid);  //btnid has the value textModel or textModel2 depending on the button clicked
    $scope.btnid += 'Hello';  //I want that instead of btnid, textModel gets appended
});
```

Now in the controller I want to write it as `$scope.textModel += 'Hello';` instead of `$scope.parameter`, So tht when I press first button, the `contenteditable div` with ng-model as textModel gets appended and when I press second button, the `contenteditable div` with ng-model as textModel2 gets appended

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access property by variable name:

```
$rootScope.$on('selectedCode', function(event, args) {
    $scope[btnid] += 'Hello';
});
```